# Webform 4 passing in email token into the redirect url confirmation page

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

This is for Drupal 7 and webform 4. I'm trying to pass in an email token value submitted from the previous webform page into the confirmation url. But it shows up blank. And the token browser dialog isn't working so I can't see how it should be formatted.

How do I reference the email field value token in the webform?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The token value is this:

`[submission:values:email]`

You can see all of it using this:

`[submission:values]`